# Paint program controls and components?

Tags: wpf, winforms, components

What components or 3d party controls exist for creating a paint or canvas based program similar to Photoshop or ArtRage for WinForms and WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Canvas control. There's an introduction to it [here](http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html). You can customize the hell out of it using adorners and mouse events as well.